# Move file from one folder to another on HDFS in Scala / Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have two paths, one for a file and one for a folder. I would like to move the file into that folder on HDFS. How can I do that in Scala? I'm using Spark, too

Bonus if the same code will work for Windows paths too, just like reading/writing files on HDFS, but not required.

I have tried the following:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.moveFromLocalFile(something, something2)
```

And I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong
>   FS: hdfs:/user/o/datasets/data.txt, expected: file:///

Same goes for `moveToLocalFile()` because they are meant to transfer files between filesystems, not within a filesystem. I have also tried `fs.rename()` but that did not do anything at all (no error or anything either).

I basically create files in one directory (writing to them with a stream) and once they are done they need to moved into a different directory. This different directory is monitored by Spark streaming and I have had some issues when Spark streaming tries to work with not finished files

Comment: *Spark streaming tries to work with not finished files*. You need to explicitly ignore any files starting with a period or underscore

Comment: When I create the files, in their temporary form they still have the same filename however they have size 0 (bytes) until they are finished, then they have the final size and the same name.

Comment: Yes, and unless you ignore them, Spark Streaming throws errors

Comment: How can I detect the size in my program? Since the filename does not change

Comment: I don't understand the question, but it seems unrelated to the original post

Comment: It's indirectly related, you said to ignore temporary files. I said that the only thing that marks a file as temporary is when its size is 0, so I wondered how  that would be possible to do?

Comment: There are also dot-files and `_SUCCESS` files that spark generates. Both are typically empty, but you can use a `FileStatus` HDFS object if you really need the size. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following Scala code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

val srcPath = new Path(srcFilePath)
val destPath = new Path(destFilePath)

hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(srcPath, destPath)
```

You should also check if Spark has the HADOOP_CONF_DIR variable set in the conf/spark-env.sh file. This will make sure that Spark is going to find the Hadoop configuration settings.

The dependencies for the build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.0"
```

**OR**

you can used IOUtils from apache commons to copy data from InputStream to OutputStream

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;



val hadoopconf = new Configuration();
val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopconf);

//Create output stream to HDFS file
val outFileStream = fs.create(new Path("hdfs://<namenode>:<port>/output_path"))

//Create input stream from local file
val inStream = fs.open(new Path("hdfs://<namenode>:<port>/input_path"))

IOUtils.copy(inStream, outFileStream)

//Close both files
inStream.close()
outFileStream.close()
```

Comment: Unfornately the first solution doesn't work, how can I check whether `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is set? Also the second solution is not viable for my system. I basically create files in one directory (writing to them with a stream) and once they are done they need to moved into a different directory. This different directory is monitored by Spark streaming and I have had some issues when Spark streaming tries to work with not finished files.

Comment: @osk Your question has no mention of Spark... And `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is an environment variable, so search how you look for them for your respective OS, or if you are using Spark, then open the spark-env.sh file, and set it there

Comment: @Sahil, I am working on the same solution and trying to find a way to copy a large dataset in a distributed manner, as i see IOUtils is a non-hadoop package org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils it may not work in a distributed manner. Could you please confirm IOUtis can work in a distributed file copy. I am trying to copy a file files in a HDFS to another HDFS directory on same cluster

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileAlreadyExistsException, FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}

val srcFileSystem: FileSystem = FileSystemUtil
  .apply(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  .getFileSystem(sourceFile)
val dstFileSystem: FileSystem = FileSystemUtil
  .apply(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  .getFileSystem(sourceFile)
FileUtil.copy(
  srcFileSystem,
  new Path(new URI(sourceFile)),
  dstFileSystem,
  new Path(new URI(targetFile)),
  true,
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```