# Copy file from Hdfs to Hdfs scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Is there a known way using Hadoop api / spark scala to copy files from one directory to another on Hdfs ?

I have tried using copyFromLocalFile but was not helpful

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226882/move-file-from-one-folder-to-another-on-hdfs-in-scala-spark

Comment: That’s for copying from local file system to Hdfs . I want to copy internally in Hdfs to another folder

Answer (score 6):

Try Hadoop's `FileUtil.copy()` command, as described here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)

```
val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val srcPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://my/src/path")
val dstPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://my/dst/path")

org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(
srcPath.getFileSystem(conf), 
srcPath, 
dstPath.getFileSystem(conf), 
dstPath, 
true, 
conf
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above but it moves the file rather than just making a copy.

Comment: Read the link, you just need to change true -> false in my example.

Comment: even after setting the flag to false... it tries to delete the file... how to fix this

Answer (score -2):

As I've understand your question, the answer is as easy as abc. Actually, there is no difference between your OS filesystem and some other distributed versions in the fundamental concepts like copying files in them. That is true that each would have its own rules in commands. For instance, when you want to copy a file from one directory to another you can do something like:

```
hdfs dfs -cp /dir_1/file_1.txt /dir_2/file_1_new_name.txt
```

The first part of the example command is just to let the command to be routed to the true destination not the OS's own file system.

for further reading you can use: [copying data in hdfs](https://www.thomashenson.com/copying-data-in-hdfs/)

Comment: This is using shell and not scala / spark programming

Comment: you said a known way, there is no known standard way to do such thing with the tools that are not designed to do so. The standard one is the mentioned one. why do you want to do it using spark?

Comment: I have a bunch of Json files in multiple directories and I want to copy them to a another directory so that I may read it using hive by pointing hive table to that Hdfs location

Comment: ok, do you need this copy to be done in each time your spark program starts running? or you may need it for the first time? if its needed to be done why don't you use the shell command? if these data are provided using another process, why don't you set the process to save its output to the destination you want to access to using hive?

Comment: It’s a workflow and cannot be changed . I’m looking for a solution to copy files using spark each time the job runs

Comment: that's a wrong workflow. it's as like as moving a spoon using a tractor. you can write a spark program to load the source directory, then save them on the destination you want. The other solution is to implement what you want to do with you hive in the data transporter spark program describe above at this comment. Good job @RData

Comment: I know I can load hive or infact any source using spark but this is my use Usecase. Right or wrong - this is how it needs to be done for the moment .

Comment: This is only part of my workflow and needs to happen on the background. I know that I can use spark to load any source but this is my usecase presently