# Using scala API, How do I copy all files of one HDFS location to another HDFS location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Using scala , I would like to copy all files inside srcFilePath to destFilePath, but the below code throws error
Can someone help me on fixing this error and solution for copying the files

```
 scala> val srcFilePath = "/development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/"
 srcFilePath: String = /development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/

 scala> val destFilePath = "/development/staging/dest_b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/"
 destFilePath: String = /development/staging/dest_b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/

 scala> val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
  hadoopConf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml

  scala> val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
  hdfs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1792011619_1, ugi=be9dusr@INTERNAL.IMSGLOBAL.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]]

 scala>

  scala> val srcPath = new Path(srcFilePath)
 srcPath: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path = /development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032

  scala> val destPath = new Path(destFilePath)
  destPath: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path = /development/staging/dest_b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032

 scala>

 scala> hdfs.copy(srcPath, destPath)
 <console>:52: error: value move is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
   hdfs.copy(srcPath, destPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875348/copy-file-from-hdfs-to-hdfs-scala/56878547)

> ```
> Try Hadoop's FileUtil.copy() command, as described here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
>
> val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
> val srcPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://my/src/path")
> val dstPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://my/dst/path")
>
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(
> srcPath.getFileSystem(conf), 
> srcPath, 
> dstPath.getFileSystem(conf), 
> dstPath, 
> true, 
> conf
> )
> ```

Comment: Yes, This code is working , I would to unzip the file and put that in to dstPath. Basically i need to read a zip file from srcPath and unzip it and place the unzipped file inside dstPath. Is there a option  to do that